# How to use ionic creator with Yeoman Ionic Generator?

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, ionic-framework, yeoman-generator

I create some views ui with **creator.ionic.io** and now i wanted to scaffolded my project using **generator-ionic**(yeoman). Unfortunately i see no options to use my UIs created on creator.ionic.io.

How to use created views on **creator.ionic.io** with generator-ionic?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just copy-paste your view code in your newly generated ionic application.

There's no magic way here, this is manual work.

Also, feel free to open an issue on the generator-ionic repository if you think they should add a subgenerator to create view from scratch (better than an issue, send a pull request).